# Magento 2 - Module Instalation without CLI

Tags: magento2, module, command-line

Hey guys I have created a php file in the public_html folder and writed the following code:

```
<?php system('php bin\magento module:enable Wisedat_PDFInvoiceFile');
system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade'); // You can change command as
you want.
```

And when I go to run the command in http://mydomain/command.php

the only thing that show´s up is a blank page !!

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want this?

Comment: what the output of this file

Comment: please change backslash in first command to same as second command  in `bin/magento`

Comment: @PrashantValanda i think the output is a module instalation

Comment: @Piyush done it still nothing

Comment: @SukumarGorai to install a module

Comment: try to run command one by one

Comment: @Piyush done it still a blank page without success or failed page

Comment: Do you running command in developer mode also check display error is on or not?

Comment: @PrashantValanda I don´t know where I can check that ? im a begginer

Comment: Go to app/etc/bootstrap.php uncomment ini_set('display_error',1); line. Then run command file again

Comment: @PrashantValanda still a blank page

Comment: I guess that you donot have CLI command at server.As per as, magento 2, you cannot do anything without doing command

Comment: @AmitBera yes i dont have i already emailed the guy from the domain and he told me that they dont give ssh service so i basicly don´t haveany opportunity to use CLI :(

Comment: @AmitBera do you know how to install it with a php file ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `php bin\magento module:enable Wisedat_PDFInvoiceFile` is wrong

It should be

```
php bin/magento module:enable Wisedat_PDFInvoiceFile
```

**You have to run static content deploy and di compile commands after run setup upgrade**

Also, you can use `php shell_exce` as in below code

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','6G');
shell_exec('php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento module:enable Wisedat_PDFInvoiceFile');
shell_exec('php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade');
shell_exec('php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile');
shell_exec('php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f');
?>
```

.

***But I am not sure that how much this script will work as you might get the error of execution time and memory limit during the running of this script from browser.***